# Naive pattern matching - How to count occurrences

Tags: python, count

I am using the naive pattern matching function in python to find the pattern of p in text t and the output returns the occurrences of p in text t.

But I am not able to write a function that will count the number of occurrences.

```
    def naive(p, t):
        occurrences = []
        for i in range(len(t) - len(p) + 1):  # loop over alignments
            match = True
            for j in range(len(p)):  # loop over characters for the pattern
                if t[i+j] != p[j]:  # compare characters in the inner loop
                    match = False
                    break
            if match:
                occurrences.append(i)  # all chars matched; record
        return occurrences
    t = ('TATACGAFGATAGAFAGAYHTATATAHHGTATATATATATATTA')
    p = ('TA')
    naive(p,t)
    print(naive(p,t))
```

Output is [0, 2, 10, 20, 22, 24, 29, 31, 33, 35, 37, 39, 42]

I want to count the number of occurrences like 13

Comment: please provide the code to test, thx

Comment: not in the comments. Edit the question. it's not readable in the comments

Comment: `len(naive(p, t))`?..

Comment: len(naive(p,t) works when t has a defined text. But if I am calling t from a file placed in directory it does not work. any suggestions

Comment: again please provide the code for the error...

Comment: @Sayse - this works fine when t has text defined here. But when I am calling text for multiple files stored in directory, it returns the length as 1.

Comment: Hi, Got the solution , used os walk function and helped

Answer (score 0):

After using the OS walk , it helped to call the directory and the files. Then used print(len(naive(p,t))) which provided the required count